# Glue-Spark transform to Postgres time data type

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, aws-glue

Postgres has a [time](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/datatype-datetime.html) data type. I am trying to insert rows into postgres from a glue job. Given the code:

```
applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = SelectFromCollection, mappings = ("event_time", "time", "event_time", "time")
```

So **timestamp** and **date** work just fine. But if the column is of type "time" it is failing with error: **IllegalArgumentException: 'Invalid type name time'**

Since this is py-spark it is not clear to me which output datatypes are supported.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue and implementing a simple trick worked out for me **Apache spark** doesn't support time data type, spark has only TimestampType and DateType .As Glue Dynamic frame is wrapper around spark dataframe glue interprets time datatype values as timestamp data type and adds a default date to the source time value "1970–01–01 " which is the unix epoch start time , for example a value stored as 13:00:00 becomes "1970–01–01 13:00:00" in glue dynamic frame .

#### Try this

```
# Fetch the event_time of every DynamicRecord and extract time by removing default date '1970-01-01 '
def map_function(dynamicRecord):
    time = str(dynamicRecord["event_time"])
    dynamicRecord["event_time"] = time[11:19]
    return dynamicRecord

# Apply the function to all the DynamicRecord
mapping3 = Map.apply(frame = S3bucket_node1, f = map_function, transformation_ctx = "mapping3")


ApplyMapping_node2 = ApplyMapping.apply(
    frame=mapping3,
    mappings=[
          # add other columns
          ("event_time", "string", "event_time", "string"),
    ],
    transformation_ctx="ApplyMapping_node2",
)
```